# Create new range name from an =OFFSET range name

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a new range name from an old one with this code:

```
  Dim Range1 As Range
  Set Range1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName").Range("OldRangeName")
  ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="NewRangeName", RefersTo:=Range1
```

The source range ("OldRangeName")  is defined as:

```
  =OFFSET('SheetName'!$B$3,0,0,COUNTA('SheetName'!$B:$B)-2,1)
```

But the above code results the NewRangeEnds  being defined not with the =OFFSET above, but the with the range that the =OFFSET results in.

For example, the new range might be:

```
  ='SheetName'!$B$3:$B$40
```

How can I have the new range be an =OFFSET formula like the source.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Does `RefersTo:=Range1.Address` work?

Comment: `RefersTo:=Activeworkbook.Names("OldRangename").RefersTo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `RefersTo:=Range1` to `RefersTo:=Range1.RefersTo`

But this will only work if you change the range to a name:

```
Dim Name1 As Name
Set Name1 = ActiveWorkbook.Names("OldRangeName")
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="NewRangeName", RefersTo:=Name1.RefersTo
```